# how to convert a string to byte to pass into the byteArray

Tags: android, bluetooth, iot

I am trying to change the color of the light bulb from a colorpicker.

This is my code

```
 ColorPickerDialogBuilder
                        .with(this)
                        .setTitle("Choose color")
                        .initialColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
                        .wheelType(ColorPickerView.WHEEL_TYPE.FLOWER)
                        .density(12)
                        .setOnColorSelectedListener(new OnColorSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onColorSelected(int selectedColor) {
                                Toast.makeText(mBluetoothLeService, ""+Integer.toHexString(selectedColor), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                String abc = Integer.toHexString(selectedColor);
                                String aa = "7f";
                                byte bb = 0x & 7f;
                                String[] split = abc.split("");



                                BluetoothGattService Service = bluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000ffd5-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
                                BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac = Service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("0000ffd9-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
                                byte[] byteArray1 = { 0x56,  0xff, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x2c, 0x00, (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0xaa};
                                charac.setValue(byteArray1);
                            }
                        })
                        .setPositiveButton("ok", new ColorPickerClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selectedColor, Integer[] allColors) {
                                //changeBackgroundColor(selectedColor);

                               // byte byte1 =
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            }
                        })
                        .build()
                        .show();
```

in the onColorSelected method, I get a hex string of the selected colour for eg "7ff002c".i want to split this string like "ff","00","2c"

now as you can see there is a byteArray down the code

I want to merge this string in the values of byteArray like

```
byte[] byteArray1 = { 0x56,  0x"ff", (byte) 0x"00", (byte) 0x"2c", 0x00, (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0xaa}; //note the inverted comma's
```

How can i do this.is this logic feasible? do you have any another logic?

Please Help

Comment: It's kind of ironic that it's your own code converting the integer colors into a hex string in the first place.   If you worked with the integer instead the split would be simpler, and there are probably functions for getting the channel values from a color anyway.  Of course you can parse the integer back out of the hex string if you really want to.

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this : `byte[] b = string.getBytes();`

Comment: int color = (int)Long.parseLong(myColorString, 16);
int r = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = (color >> 0) & 0xFF;    gave me respected r,g and b which i passed in the byte array and it worked!

Comment: No, this would produce the bytes comprising the printable characters representing the hex value, what is actually wanted is the color code as a series of three 8-bit byte values, not six ASCII characters.